# Is there a way to prioritize writes from two different channels?

Tags: netty

I have a set of channels that I’m writing to, and I’d like a way to say: write to channel A BEFORE writing to channel B. The questions I see mention order within a channel, but I haven’t seen anything about ways to order between them.

The use case is an attempt at ordering io to disk, where each channel is accessing interleaved sections of a file. It’s better if they can be handled in order, s.t the seek costs are minimized.

This likely means picking the same event loop for the set of channels that needs the ordering. If that’s possible, the next part, I believe, would be to call flush in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like this in Netty.... Writes will be in the done in the same order you are executing them. If you need any special order algorithm you will need to implement it yourself. That said remember that everything is async so even if you call write(...) it may be executed later for various reasons, for example when the Channel becomes non-writable.